# Russian phone number gets formatted on dial

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm currently facing a problem on iOS (I tried on iPhone 5/iOS 9 and iPhone 6 Plus/iOS 8). My goal is to open the phone application and dial a russian number.
The number is like

> 8 800 123 45 67

To be short, I'm just doing

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"tel:88001234567"]
```

Whenever I'm trying to call, the phone number gets formatted and loses one 0 to become

> +880 123 4567

And when I try to add the indicative which is 007, the phone number called loses one 8 to become

> 00 7 (800) 123-45-67

Last thing, when I try to use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"telprompt:88001234567"]
```

It correctly shows me

> 00 7 (8800) 123-45-67

But when I press "Call", the phone number called is

> 00 7 (800) 123-45-67

Did anyone already have this problem? Is this a normal behavior on iOS? On Android the dial application doesn't format the phone number.

**Edit:** Thanks to Pekka, when we check this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Russia we can see:

> Calls from outside Russia: +7 ABC xxx-xx-xx where ABC is the area code

Then the fact that one 8 drops when adding the country code is normal.

Other point, it seems that the first 8 is a long-distance prefix that might be not necessary. I'm gonna try to contact our customer to be sure about this.

**Edit 2:** Well, our customer told us that the first 8 is required, I'm gonna have to find a way around.

Comment: `+` is the only standard prefix for international numbers AFAIK. Have you tried `+7 8 800 123 45 67`?

Comment: Yep I also tried this!

Comment: What result are you getting with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"tel:+788001234567"]`?

Comment: The number called becomes +7 (800) 123-45-67

Comment: It drops the first `8`? Hmm, that's weird.

Comment: Yep! Even if I try to format the number directly, by adding these ( ) - , it's still the same result.

Comment: Could it be that iOS knows something about this specific numbering block that we don't? I can't see the `880` block as a valid numbering block in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Russia In fact,  `881`-`889` show up as "reserved"... although just removing the first `8` would definitely be a bug

Comment: Actually on this list we can find 800 as free phone. The number expected really is 8 800 123 45 67 as it's already showed in this format on the russian website of our customer, but I guess it's a special kind of number as it's one for the whole country, and not assigned to any zone.

Comment: Calls from outside Russia, +7 ABC xxx-xx-xx, where ABC is the area code. Well then the format when adding +7 is logic, but not the loss of one 0 when  not adding it.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article, the first `8` seems to be a long-distance prefix. Maybe that's not necessary at all, and iOS is formatting the number to conform with the numbering pattern? Might be worth checking with the customer.

Comment: Probably, I'm gonna try to contact him as soon as possible, and tell you what is the result!

Answer (score 0):

lose the first 8 add +7 prefix:
+78001234567